# Srapping inflation from dropdown box in Banxico

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract the dropdown values from [Mexico's central](http://www.banxico.org.mx/portal-inflacion/inflacion.html) given a month and year input, I would like to avoid using Selenium because I don't want to open a chrome window every time I run my script. Here's what I've tried so far:

> Twill

```
from twill.commands import *
go("http://www.banxico.org.mx/portal-inflacion/inflacion.html")
showforms()
Output: Form name=_BBM_MenuForm (#1)
## ## __Name__________________ __Type___ __ID________ 
__Value__________________
1     url                      hidden    url          
/AplBusquedasBM2/bgenwww_in.jsp 
2     appname                  hidden    appname      bmsearch 
3     _action                  hidden    _action      search 
4     _lang                    hidden    _lang        es 
5     _userquery               text      _userquery   Buscar... 
6     submit                   submit    (None)        
7     _P_BM_Deposito           select    _P_BM_De ... ['B', 'M', '_', 'W', 'W', 'W', ';',  ...
```

I think the `submit`input is what I'm looking for but I don't see how to input month and year data.

> Mechanize

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()

b = br.open("http://www.banxico.org.mx/portal-inflacion/inflacion.html")

b.select_form(nr=0)

form = br.form

print(form)

Output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pago_ext.py", line 16, in <module>
    b.select_form(nr=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_response.py", line 106, in __getattr__
    return getattr(wrapped, name)
AttributeError: closeable_response instance has no attribute 'select_form'
```

How can I access the dropdown menu considering I don't know much about HTML???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much easier to interact with a RESTful API than to strip data from HTML. With a bit of inspection using Chromes Inspect tool, it was easy to duplicate the REST requests using Python urllib. The following works with Python 3.

You can easily change the 'fecha' date to get the date you want. Also you will have to extract what you need out of the XML reply.

```
import urllib.request

headers = {'accion':'dato',
           'idSeries':'SP30577,SP30578,SP30579,SP74660,SP74661,SP74662,SP74663,SP74664,SP74665',
           'decimales':'2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2',
           'fecha':'01/02/2017'
           }

url = 'http://www.banxico.org.mx/tipcamb/datosieajax'

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(headers)
req = urllib.request.Request(url + '?' + data)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you carefully inspect the page (**HINT**: look for requests being made in your Network tab (`CTRL + Shift + E` in Firefox)), you will notice that the data arrives in `json` format each time you change the values (month/year) of the drop-down box. The URL is always the same, only the date at the end is changed. Knowing that, with a few tricks, you can easily get all the data.

Here is your scraper:

```
import requests
from collections import OrderedDict

def get_annual_data(year):

    data = []

    for i in range(1, 13):
        url = 'http://www.banxico.org.mx/tipcamb/datosieajax?accion=dato&idSeries=SP30577,SP30578,SP30579,SP74660,SP74661,SP74662,SP74663,SP74664,SP74665&decimales=2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2&fecha=01/{0}/{1}'.format('0' + str(i) if i < 10 else i, str(year))
        x = requests.get(url).json()
        data.append(x)

    years_data = OrderedDict()

    for i, x in enumerate(data):

        month_data = OrderedDict()

        month_data['INPC índice general'] = {
            'Mensual': data[i]['body'][0]['mensaje'],
            'Acumulada en el año': data[i]['body'][2]['mensaje'],
            'Anual': data[i]['body'][1]['mensaje']
        }

        month_data['INPC subyacente'] = {
            'Mensual': data[i]['body'][3]['mensaje'],
            'Acumulada en el año': data[i]['body'][4]['mensaje'],
            'Anual': data[i]['body'][5]['mensaje']
        }

        month_data['INPC no subyacente'] = {
            'Mensual': data[i]['body'][6]['mensaje'],
            'Acumulada en el año': data[i]['body'][7]['mensaje'],
            'Anual': data[i]['body'][8]['mensaje']
        }

        years_data[i + 1] = month_data

    return years_data

def get_data(start_year, end_year):

    all_data = OrderedDict()

    for i in range(start_year, end_year + 1):
        all_data[i] = get_annual_data(i)

    return all_data
```

Basically, you run the scraper with `get_data(start_year, end_year)` (for instance, `get_data(2010, 2016)`). The information will be in a nice OrderedDict, with each year being a key, and all the data corresponding to that year being a value. You can pretty-print it if you want to see how the structure looks like (`from pprint import pprint; pprint(get_data(2010, 2016))`). You can access the values, for instance, like this: `print(get_data(2014, 2016)[2014][1]['INPC índice general'])`, which would give you: `{'Mensual': '0.89', 'Acumulada en el año': '0.89', 'Anual': '4.48'}`